# Program Running Pika Throwing AMQPConnectionError

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

Going through the Rabbit MQ Pika HelloWorld tutorial found here:
https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-python.html

The problem is, I keep getting this error whenever I run my receive script:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "receive.py", line 5, in <module>
    pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost'))

  File "C:\Users\Colin Warn\PycharmProjects\untitled2\venv\lib\site-packages\pika\adapters\blocking_connection.py", line 360, in __init__
    self._impl = self._create_connection(parameters, _impl_class)

  File "C:\Users\Colin Warn\PycharmProjects\untitled2\venv\lib\site-packages\pika\adapters\blocking_connection.py", line 451, in _create_connection
 
raise self._reap_last_connection_workflow_error(error)

pika.exceptions.AMQPConnectionError
```

Here's the code I'm attempting to run:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pika

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(
    pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()

channel.queue_declare(queue='hello')


def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    print(" [x] Received %r" % body)


channel.basic_consume(
    queue='hello', on_message_callback=callback, auto_ack=True)

print(' [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C')
channel.start_consuming()
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Do you have a rabbit server running in your machine?

Comment: Not sure how to check.  I've also recreated their send.py script that I thought would create one, but it just sends me the same error.  I have more than 200 MB on my disk drive, so I'm not sure what else would be causing this.

Comment: You have to install a rabbit in your machine check out this https://www.rabbitmq.com/download.html after installing rabbit server go back and rerun the script. I hope it goes well.

Comment: That fixed it, thank you!

Comment: If you already have installed rabbitmq on your machine make sure the connection uri is correct

Answer (score 23):

All you need to do is installing RabbitMQ in your PC. You can simply run with docker using the command below in another terminal, and re-run your code

```
docker run -it --rm --name rabbitmq -p 5672:5672 -p 15672:15672 rabbitmq:3-management
```

Comment: `sudo docker run -it --rm --name rabbitmq -p 5672:5672 -p 15672:15672 rabbitmq:3-management` in my case it was run as super user.

Answer (score 5):

You need to install RabbitMQ on your machine:
https://rabbitmq.com/download.html

After installing RabbitMQ server re-run the script.

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps:

1. sudo apt-get install rabbitmq-server
2. sudo systemctl start rabbitmq-server
3. sudo systemctl enable rabbitmq-server

Comment: The questioner seems to be a windows user. But you seem to have answered when using ubuntu OS.

Comment: This helped me for my linux issue. I needed to install this for PIKA.

Answer (score 1):

I get a different solution, instead of using **host='localhost'**, use the rabbitmq docker **container ipaddress** (in my case it was 172.17.0.2), you can get that ip with the command:

```
docker inspect <container_id>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me this problem arises when i updated my system.

And the possible reasons are either **rabbitmq-server is not installed** or **rabbitmq-server is not running**.

try to run the below command in ubuntu

```
sudo systemctl status rabbimtmq-server
```

if server is not running, use below command to start the server.

```
sudo systemctl restart rabbitmq-server
```

if everthing is fine, then your code will run without any problem.

In case if your are unable to start/restart the server, the re-install the rabbitmq from below link.

[rabbitmq installation guide](https://www.rabbitmq.com/download.html)

In my case, i solved the problem by reinstalling the rabbitmq.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue. Then I enabled (open) the 5672 port in my hosting device. Then it solved.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34891014)