# pika.exceptions.AMQPConnectionError in Python pod when trying to connect to RabbitMQ in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq, pika

In Kubernetes I have deployed RabbitMQ pod, service and ingress.
I have access to RabbitMQ UI and I added a user that has access to virtual host "/" and a password.

I tried to create a Python pod that connects to RabbitMQ and create a queue but I have the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/dump_notify/producer.py", line 40, in <module>
    main()
  File "/dump_notify/producer.py", line 24, in main
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)
  File "/opt/app-root/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 360, in __init__
    self._impl = self._create_connection(parameters, _impl_class)
  File "/opt/app-root/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 451, in _create_connection
    raise self._reap_last_connection_workflow_error(error)
pika.exceptions.AMQPConnectionError
```

My Python code is this:

```
import pika
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler

class FileEventHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def __init__(self, channel):
        self.channel = channel

    def on_created(self, event):
        if not event.is_directory:
            self.channel.basic_publish(exchange='', routing_key='myqueue',
                                        body='New file has been added to SFTP : %s' % event.src_path)

def main():
    credentials = pika.PlainCredentials('Lbeodeobf', 'test')
    print('Logged')

    parameters = pika.ConnectionParameters('X',
                                   5672,
                                   '/',
                                   credentials)
    print(parameters)

    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)
    print("Connection...")
    channel = connection.channel()

    channel.queue_declare(queue='myqueue')

    event_handler = FileEventHandler(channel)

    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path='/mnt/', recursive=False)
    observer.start()
    observer.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Where can I be wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

As you are getting  `pika.exceptions.AMQPConnectionError` is not related to python code which you run, this is related to the connection error for  RabbitMQ.  So,  you need to install [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/download.html) on your PC or server . Post successful installation if it is a linux server then  run this commands `sudo systemctl start rabbitmq-server` and `sudo systemctl enable rabbitmq-server`  which will start and enable the rabbit server and then run the python code which may resolve your issue.

Comment: RabbitMQ has been deployed in a kubernetes pod. It is up and running. It has a k8s service. Do I have to enable rabbitmq-server ?

Comment: @jos97: Yes you need to enable rabbitmq-server to get the connection successful.

Comment: I don't understand the difference between pod where I have rabbitmq running and rabbit-mq-server. Pod is running, I tried to enable rabbitmq-server with exec in pod but didn't work : "couldn't bind, it is in use by another node" the node is my pod that is running

Comment: In the Pod where you are running, install the RabbitMQ server and run the python code. refer to this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55718163/) for more information.